# Python pandas dataframe backfill based on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   Bool   Hour
0  False  12
1  False  24
2  False  12
3  False  24
4  True   12
5  False  24
6  False  12
7  False  24
8  False  12
9  False  24
10 False  12
11 True   24
```

and I would like to backfill the True value in 'Bool' column to the point when 'Hour' first reaches '12'.  The result would be something like this:

```
   Bool   Hour  Result
0  False  12    False
1  False  24    False
2  False  12    True      <- desired backfill
3  False  24    True      <- desired backfill
4  True   12    True
5  False  24    False
6  False  12    False
7  False  24    False
8  False  12    False
9  False  24    False
10 False  12    True      <- desired backfill
11 True   24    True
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This is a little bit hard to achieve , here we can use `groupby` with  `idxmax`

```
s=(~df.Bool&df.Hour.eq(12)).iloc[::-1].groupby(df.Bool.iloc[::-1].cumsum()).transform('idxmax')
df['result']=df.index>=s.iloc[::-1]
df
Out[375]: 
     Bool  Hour  result
0   False    12   False
1   False    24   False
2   False    12    True
3   False    24    True
4    True    12    True
5   False    24   False
6   False    12   False
7   False    24   False
8   False    12   False
9   False    24   False
10  False    12    True
11   True    24    True
```

Comment: In the edge case when the last `False` group doesn't have `True` to `bfill`, this still fills `True` ;p

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do:

```
s = df['Bool'].shift(-1)
df['Result'] = df['Bool'] | s.where(s).groupby(df['Hour'].eq(12).cumsum()).bfill()
```

Output:

```
     Bool  Hour  Result
0   False    12   False
1   False    24   False
2   False    12    True
3   False    24    True
4    True    12    True
5   False    24   False
6   False    12   False
7   False    24   False
8   False    12   False
9   False    24   False
10  False    12    True
11   True    24    True
```

Answer (score 1):

create a groupID `s` on consecutive `False` and separate `True` from them. Groupby on `Hour` equals `12` by using `s`. Use transform `sum` and `cumsum` to get the count of `True` on `12` from bottom-up on each group and return `True` on `0` and `or` with values of `Bool`

```
s = df.Bool.ne(df.Bool.shift()).cumsum()
s1 = df.where(df.Bool).Bool.bfill()
g = df.Hour.eq(12).groupby(s)
df['bfill_Bool'] = (g.transform('sum') - g.cumsum()).eq(0) & s1 | df.Bool

Out[905]:
     Bool  Hour  bfill_Bool
0   False    12       False
1   False    24       False
2   False    12        True
3   False    24        True
4    True    12        True
5   False    24       False
6   False    12       False
7   False    24       False
8   False    12       False
9   False    24       False
10  False    12        True
11   True    24        True
```