# Python pandas dataframe backfill based on 3 conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

An extension to my previous question:  [Python pandas dataframe backfill based on 2 conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58104114/python-pandas-dataframe-backfill-based-on-two-conditions/58106074#58106074)

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   Bool   Hour  Min
0  False  12    00
1  False  12    30
2  False  24    00
3  False  24    30
4  False  12    00
5  False  12    30
6  False  24    00
7  False  24    30
8  True   12    00
9  False  12    30
10 False  24    00
11 False  24    30
12 False  12    00
13 False  12    30
14 False  24    00
15 False  24    30
16 False  12    00
17 False  12    30
18 False  24    00
19 False  24    30
20 False  12    00
21 False  12    30
22 False  24    00
23 True   24    30
```

and I would like to backfill the True value in 'Bool' column to the point when 'Hour' first reaches '12' and 'Min' first reaches '00'. The result would be something like this:

```
   Bool   Hour  Min  Result
0  False  12    00   False
1  False  12    30   False
2  False  24    00   False
3  False  24    30   False
4  False  12    00   True    <- Desired backfill
5  False  12    30   True    <- Desired backfill
6  False  24    00   True    <- Desired backfill
7  True   24    30   True    <- Desired backfill
8  False  12    00   False
9  False  12    30   False
10 False  24    00   False
11 False  24    30   False
12 False  12    00   False
13 False  12    30   False
14 False  24    00   False
15 False  24    30   False
16 False  12    00   False
17 False  12    30   False
18 False  24    00   False
19 False  24    30   False
20 False  12    00   True    <- Desired backfill
21 False  12    30   True    <- Desired backfill
22 False  24    00   True    <- Desired backfill
23 True   24    30   True    <- Desired backfill
```

Any help is very very much appreciated.  Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I edited the question.

Comment: why row 8 filled to row 7? shouldn't row 11 be backfilled till 8?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
m = df['Hour'].eq(12) & df['Min'].eq(0) 
df['Result'] = df['Bool'].shift(-1).groupby(m.cumsum()).transform('any') | df['Bool']
```

**Explanation**:

1. Create boolean mask by all condition to `m` with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==`
2. Then use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) by one row up with `-1`
3. Create groups by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)
4. Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for test `True` per groups by `g`
5. Last chain boolean column with `|` for bitwise OR

---

```
m = df['Hour'].eq(12) & df['Min'].eq(0) 

print (df.assign(m = df['Hour'].eq(12) & df['Min'].eq(0),
                 shift = df['Bool'].shift(-1),
                 g = m.cumsum(),
                 transform = df['Bool'].shift(-1).groupby(m.cumsum()).transform('any'),
                 Result=df['Bool'].shift(-1).groupby(m.cumsum()).transform('any')|df['Bool']))

     Bool  Hour  Min      m  shift  g  transform  Result
0   False    12    0   True  False  1      False   False
1   False    12   30  False  False  1      False   False
2   False    24    0  False  False  1      False   False
3   False    24   30  False  False  1      False   False
4   False    12    0   True  False  2       True    True
5   False    12   30  False  False  2       True    True
6   False    24    0  False  False  2       True    True
7   False    24   30  False   True  2       True    True
8    True    12    0   True  False  3      False    True
9   False    12   30  False  False  3      False   False
10  False    24    0  False  False  3      False   False
11  False    24   30  False  False  3      False   False
12  False    12    0   True  False  4      False   False
13  False    12   30  False  False  4      False   False
14  False    24    0  False  False  4      False   False
15  False    24   30  False  False  4      False   False
16  False    12    0   True  False  5      False   False
17  False    12   30  False  False  5      False   False
18  False    24    0  False  False  5      False   False
19  False    24   30  False  False  5      False   False
20  False    12    0   True  False  6       True    True
21  False    12   30  False  False  6       True    True
22  False    24    0  False   True  6       True    True
23   True    24   30  False    NaN  6       True    True
```

---

Add new condition to @Wen answer:

```
m = (~df.Bool&df.Hour.eq(12)&df.Min.eq(0))
s=m.iloc[::-1].groupby(df.Bool.iloc[::-1].cumsum()).transform('idxmax')
df['result']=df.index>=s.iloc[::-1]
```

Also to Quang Hoang answer like:

```
s = df['Bool'].shift(-1)
m = df['Hour'].eq(12) & df['Min'].eq(0)
df['Result'] = df['Bool'] | s.where(s).groupby(m.cumsum()).bfill()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it using groupby and backfill

I have broken steps for clarity

```py
group = ((df.Hour == "12") & (df.Min == "00")).cumsum()
bool_col = df["Bool"].where(df["Bool"], np.nan)

df["result2"]=bool_col.groupby(group).backfill() == 1
print(df)
```